# Swagger editor return me to Petstore YAML code

Tags: api, yaml, swagger

I got a huge problem, please advise!

```
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "This is a sample server Petstore server.  You can find out more about     Swagger at [http://swagger.io](http://swagger.io) or on [irc.freenode.net, #swagger](http://swagger.io/irc/).      For this sample, you can use the api key `special-key` to test the authorization     filters."
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: "Swagger Petstore"
  termsOfService: "http://swagger.io/terms/"
  contact:
    email: "apiteam@swagger.io"
  license:
    name: "Apache 2.0"
    url: "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
host: "petstore.swagger.io"`
```

Somehow Swagger editor returned my code to the Petstore and I don't know how to return it back. I need your help please.
So much work I don't want to lose it.

I pressed the return on the browser and now I can't find my code.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the same browser as before? If you loaded editor via `http://` try `https://` and vice versa. The HTTP and HTTPS versions use separate `localStorage`.

Comment: yes i am using the same browser. I just pressed refresh on it and got to the default yaml :( I don't know what to do ...

Comment: Did you try changing the address bar from `http://` to `https://` or vice versa?

Comment: yes it is not working :(